# How to clear "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException" error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am a newbie to python so please excuse me. I have no background in programming, I am just trying things to smooth out something for me by automating.

I found other similar questions but my problem still persists after following some of the solutions posted.

I am trying to automate uploading files to a website, the website allows one file for upload at once, so I am trying to automate uploading the task of uploading one by one.

I am using selenium and I have progressed to logging in the page and attaching the file to upload. Now I am stuck as the website requires 3 tags to be inputted. There is one long field to input tags and is backed up by auto suggestion/complete. Cannot enter custom words, only those provided by website which is in auto suggestion.

The above error is displayed when I try to sendkeys() to that tag field element. Below is that element

[https://imgur.com/a/VGq7AtY]

I have tried Implicit wait and explicit wait as well but it doesn't work out, as seen below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('https://www.website.com/login')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input').send_keys('username')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/input').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/form/div[2]/button').click()



driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/header/div[1]/span[2]').click() // upload page


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/label/input').send_keys('/home/userrobin/Desktop/file.html') // file to be uploaded path

time.sleep(10)
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
tags = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tags-selector"]')))
# tags = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tags-selector"]')))
tags.send_keys('assignment')
```

Error : *selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard*

What am I missing, what can I do to identify the problem?
Thank you

EDIT

added

I tried with
`

```
(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="tags-selector"]')
```

` , it gives is *invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression Stacktrace:* , I am not sure on how to refine locator to include //input

tried

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tags-selector"]/input').send_keys('assignment')`

but it gave *selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="tags-selector"]/input*

tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tags-selector"]').click()
```

this works on that field as now I can see the cursor in the field.

but when I try send_keys(), it shows me error *not reachable by keyboard*

Comment: make sure to target the <input> tag with an attribute of type="file".  Sounds like you're hitting a hidden field.

Comment: //*[@id="tags-selector"] not sure if this is an input tag.

Comment: @pcalkins  thank you for the reply   
https://imgur.com/a/VGq7AtY    
I have used the highlighted element in above pic, as per my knowledge is it not input tag with type = "text"?

Comment: @Arundeep please check the imgur link above, thank you for the reply and your time.

Comment: Seems like Arundeep is on to something there... I didn't see your "tags.send_keys" line at the bottom.   That page does not have unique IDs.  (it should, but doesn't...)  There's two elements with ID of "tags-selector"  Refine your locator to include //input

Comment: What pcalkins said is correct just include the //input[@id=“tags-selector”] it should be fine.

Comment: I tried with (By.XPATH, '//input[@id="tags-selector"]') , it gives is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression
Stacktrace: , I am not sure on how to refine locator to include //input, sorry

Comment: tried driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tags-selector"]/input').send_keys('assignment') but it gave selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="tags-selector"]/input